# Spring-Data-MongoDB - Updates take seconds to complete?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongodb to interact with my mongodb setup. I was testing different write concerns and noticed that with **Unacknowledged write concern**, the time for updating 1000 documents was around 5-6 secs even though Unacknowledged write concern doesn't wait for any acknowledgement.
I tested the same with raw java driver and the time was around 40 msec.

What could be cause of this huge time difference between raw java driver and spring data mongodb update?

Note that I am using Unacknowledged write concern and mongodb v2.6.1 with default configurations.

Adding Code Used for comparison:-

Raw Java driver code:-

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "testdb" );

        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("product");
        WriteResult wr = null;
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            wr = collection.update(
                    new BasicDBObject("productId", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 10000000)
                                                       .append("$lt", 10001000)),
                    new BasicDBObject("$inc", new BasicDBObject("price", 100)),
                    false, true, WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println(wr + "  Time taken: " + (end - start) + " ms.");
        }
```

Spring Code:-
Config.xml

```
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="testdb" mongo-ref="mongo" />

<bean id="Unacknowledged" class="com.mongodb.WriteConcern">
    <constructor-arg name="w" type="int" value="0"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <property name="writeConcern" ref="Unacknowledged"/>
</bean>
```

Java Code for update function which is part of ProductDAOImpl:-

```
public int update(long fromProductId, long toProductId, double changeInPrice)
{
    Query query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
                            Criteria.where("productId").gte(fromProductId),
                            Criteria.where("productId").lt(toProductId)));

    Update update = new Update().inc("price", changeInPrice);

    WriteResult writeResult =
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Product.class);

    return writeResult.getN();
}
```

Accesing code:-

```
    ProductDAOImpl productDAO = new ProductDAOImpl();

    productDAO.setMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    productDAO.update(10000000, 10001000, 100);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Time taken = " + (end - start) + " ms.");
```

Schema:-

```
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("53b64d000cf273a0d95a1a3d"),
       "_class" : "springmongo.domain.Product",
       "productId" : NumberLong(6),
       "productName" : "product6",
       "manufacturer" : "company30605739",
       "supplier" : "supplier605739",
       "category" : "category30605739",
       "mfgDate" : ISODate("1968-04-26T05:00:00.881Z"),
       "price" : 665689.7224373372,
       "tags" : [
              "tag82",
              "tag61",
              "tag17"
       ],
       "reviews" : [
              {
                     "name" : "name528965",
                     "rating" : 6.5
              },
              {
                     "name" : "name818975",
                     "rating" : 7.5
              },
              {
                     "name" : "name436239",
                     "rating" : 3.9
              }
       ],
       "manufacturerAdd" : {
              "state" : "state55",
              "country" : "country155",
              "zipcode" : 718
       },
       "supplierAdd" : {
              "state" : "state69",
              "country" : "country69",
              "zipcode" : 691986
       }
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure you're testing the exact same scenarios? Without more detail on what exactly you're doing it's very hard to judge.

Comment: Yeah, I am keeping everything same. The thing is, this is happening only with updates. With insert or remove I am not seeing any considerable difference.

Comment: It would be easier for people to help you if you would share your schema, sample docs and the code used for testing.

Comment: As I understand with Unacknowledged write concern, the driver should just write the update query on the socket and return. It doesn't wait for any acknowledgement from server. 
Could it be possible that spring is internally waiting for acknowledgement?